# React child components do not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx, react-dom

Im new to react and am currently trying to render some components.
My problem is that only the parent Component is being rendered.
I also have child Components but react doesnt seem to recognize them?

This is my index where I am importing my App component.

```
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import App from './app';

function BuildApp() {
  return (
    <App />
  );
}

ReactDom.render(<BuildApp />, document.body);
```

Here is my App component.

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from './components/bootstrap-components/Container';
import TopInfo from './components/TopInfo/TopInfo';

export default function App() {
  return (
      <Container>
        <TopInfo />
      </Container>
  );
}
```

The only thing my App Component renders is Container Component not the TopInfo.
If I remove the Container component and only have TopInfo, React will render TopInfo.

Comment: You should add children in Container component.

Comment: inside the `Container` return do `{props.children}` where you want the child to appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [React children](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment).

```
function Container(props) {
   return (
     <div>
       {props.chilidren}
     </div>
   );
}
```